# In Sierra, is there a setting to keep the dock from jumping to external displays?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, dock

I am working on a MacBook Pro 2016 with 2 monitors attached. Often I look up, and the dock is now on one of the other monitors, not remaining on the MacBook, which is where I want it to be and stay. Is there a setting to make that happen? I have looked in SYS PREF for DOCK and DISPLAYS and don't see anything. Thx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

System Prefs > Mission control > Displays have separate Spaces ...disable

Though that may impact the rest of your workflow.